# using sed/awk to parse XML tags

Tags: script, sed, xml, awk

For the record, I've spent several days working on this with no luck.

I'm working with XML files with data containing something like the following:

```
<row id="67581917031" name="4022" filesize="22425" file_content_id="67581868031" lastmodify_datetime="1187126570050" group_id="67581916031"/> <row id="254115371041" name="4022" filesize="49471" file_content_id="254115361041" lastmodify_datetime="1220512827666" group_id="253405951041"/> <row id="286104505041" name="4022" filesize="3802672" file_content_id="286104455041" lastmodify_datetime="1223348052489" group_id="286104504041"/> <row id="289541609041" name="4022" filesize="42235" file_content_id="264826268041" lastmodify_datetime="1223587308419" group_id="289541607041"/> <row id="306643757002" name="4022" filesize="392560" file_content_id="243411753011" lastmodify_datetime="1218251898489" group_id="67581916031"/> <row id="367316910041" name="4022" filesize="381083" file_content_id="367316830041" lastmodify_datetime="1232592570004" group_id="74169006021"/>
```

If you look carefully, you will find that two of these records have the same "name" and "group_id". I'm trying to write a script that will find these rows and spit out the row ID, name, and group_id in question. I hoping to do was either use sed to pick up on the end of each "row" and insert a newline (\n) so then I could use `nl` to print out the number of lines, store that number in a variable, then use a for loop to run an awk command to pattern match each row id, name, and group_id and somehow check if the name and group_id are a match to any other rows, and if they're a match, print out the row id and name.

Comment: It might be easier to use an XML parser for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for those rows that have the same `name` AND `group_id`, you could do something like this (assuming you are on a *nix OS, you don't say in your question, you can just paste this directly to the command line):

```
sed 's#/>#/>\n#g' simple_file.xml |
        perl -ne 'if(/row id=.(.+?)\".+name=.(.+?)\".+group_id=.(.+?)\"/){ 
         push @{$k{join("\t",$2,$3)}},$1;} 
         END{ 
           foreach (keys(%k)){ 
            if($#{$k{$_}}>0){
                 print "$_\t",pop @{$k{$_}},"\n" 
          } }}'
```

EXPLANATION:

- `sed 's#/>#/>\n#g' simple_file.xml` : Add a newline after each entry (after each `/>`) to facilitate parsing.
- `perl -ne` :  process the file, line by line
- `/row id= ... group_id=.(\d+)/;` :  use a regex (which is generally a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936) for [X]HTML files, you may have the blood of fluffy kittens on your hands) to get the  `row_id`,`name` and `group_id`, these are saved as `$1`,`$2` and `$3` respectively.
- `push @{$k{join("\t",$2,$3)}},$1;` :  This is a bit more complex. It creates a hash of arrays called (`%k`), then it uses `join` to connect the `name` and `group_id` with a tab. Finally, it adds the `row_id` to the array. In other words, if your `row_id` is `123`, your `name` is `456` and your `group_id` is `789`, that will create an array and save it as the value of hash `%k` for key `456 789`.
- The `END{}` block is executed once, when the rest of the file has been processed. It will go through each of the keys of the hash (whose values are arrays) and print out those 
  cases where the array has more than one entry, in other words, the duplicates. The `pop` function returns the last element of an array, in this case the `row_id`.

I ran this on your example and got this output:

```
4022    67581916031 306643757002
----    ----------  ------------
 |           |           |---------------> row id
 |           |---------------------------> group id
 |---------------------------------------> name
```

If you did not see the link in the second bullet point, I would just like to stress that [You. Should. Never. Parse. [X]HTML. With. Regular. Expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936)

Comment: Could you try running this script against [this](http://chrisolin.com/simple_file.xml) and see if you experience the same results?

I did not. When running the script that you provided, it didn't return anything (and yes, I am running a *NIX environment).

Comment: EDIT: I think I see why this isn't working for me. The code I provided appears to have automatically been formatted to put each row on a separate line. The file I'm running this against has *everything* on one line.

Comment: close, but it's getting caught up in spaces rows with spaces in the 'name' value. I tried putting $2 in quotes, but it didn't seem to fix it. I'm more familiar with BASH than perl, so I'm not sure if quotes work the same way.

Comment: Nevermind. It's the regex. I'm trying to rework the name regex to properly parse the various scenarios.

Comment: @BinaryMan this kind of thing is why you should not parse HTML. Anyway, I updated it to look for all characters up to the first `"` for each of the fields. If your field values are always quoted, and also added an if so it would only save on matching lines. Try the latest, it should work.

Comment: That's what I came up with too. Lesson learned. Thanks a bunch. It's much appreciated.

Comment: The reason you spent several days on it without success is that you are using the wrong technology. If you want to parse XML, use an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

It's axiomatic that it's not possible to safely parse XML with regular expressions.  You need an XML parser.

You *can* parse known subsets of XML, but in practice that often turns out to be much harder than just learning to use an XML parser.